# Alignment of text in three columns using tabular envirnonment

Tags: tables

In the following code, I have six functions typeset in three columns.  I want the right parenthesis vertically aligned in each column and `2.5cm` between the columns.  (I use `@{ }` to put a single space between the right parenthesis and a function.  It is typeset correctly in the first column.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r@{ }lp{2.5cm}r@{ }lp{2.5cm}r@{ }l}
i.)     &   $x^{2}$     &   ii.)    &      $x^{3}$  &   iii.)   &   $\sqrt{\vert x \vert}$ \\ [2ex]
iv.)    &   $\vert x \vert$ &   v.) &   $\sin{x}$   &   vi.)    &   $\ln{x}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have too many columns, if I got you question correctly the following should be enough:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r@{ }p{2.5cm}r@{ }p{2.5cm}r@{ }l}
i.)     &   $x^{2}$     &   ii.)    &      $x^{3}$  &   iii.)   &   $\sqrt{x}$ \\ [2ex]
iv.)    &   $\vert x \vert$ &   v.) &   $\sin{x}$   &   vi.)    &   $\ln{x}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted.

Comment: I thought that `r@{ }l` put a space between the `)` and function.  I see that in your code, you kept the `l` only for the last column.

Comment: yes, because in the last column you don't need space to the right, since it is the last. You can use `p` however.

Comment: @user74973 the `@{ }` does put the space where you said. The problem with your code was that you then had a `l` for the function and the a `p{2.5cm}` which was the column for the  `ii.)`. You didn't need the `l` column

Comment: In the code in my post, I had `\begin{tabular}{r@{ }l ...`.  Are you saying that the `l` here would have aligned the roman numerals `ii.)` and `v.)` on the left?  If that is the case, I do not want to have `l` as an alignment option.  What does the `l` in your code "do"?

Comment: `l` creates the last column, where the functions are aligned to left. `p{2.5cm}` also align the content to left, the difference is that with `l` the column takes the natural width of the content, while with `p` fixes the width of the column to a certain value (2.5cm) in this case

Comment: you're very welcome : )

Comment: @user74973, and what will happen, when an equation for example in the first column will be longer than 2.5 cm?

Comment: @Zarko  With `p{2.5cm}`, the contents are aligned at the left. If the width of the contents is more than `2.5cm`, I guess the part that is outside the first `2.5cm` is not typeset.

Comment: I just wanted to draw attention to a broader view regarding the selection of types of columns. In normal circumstances `p{...}` would broke equation into more lines.

Answer (score 3):

See, if the following is what you looking for:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{rl@{\hspace{2.5cm}}rl@{\hspace{2.5cm}}rl}
i.)     &   $x^{2}$         &   ii.)    &      $x^{3}$  &   iii.)   &   $\sqrt{\vert x \vert}$ \\ 
iv.)    &   $\vert x \vert$ &   v.)     &   $\sin{x}$   &   vi.)    &   $\ln{x}$    
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

You have defined eight columns, so only first six was considered in table. To my taste is better to use `l` column type than `p{...}`.

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**
second image is generated with code as you prefer to have. Now you can observe differences:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{r@{ }>{$}l<{$} @{\hspace{2.5cm}}r@{ }>{$}l<{$} @{\hspace{2.5cm}}r@{ }>{$}l<{$} }
i.)     &   x^{2}         &   ii.)    &      x^{3}  &   iii.)   &   \sqrt{\vert x \vert} \\ 
iv.)    &   \vert x \vert &   v.)     &   \sin{x}   &   vi.)    &   \ln{x}    
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

*Note:* Your question is not very clear, so the answer is based more or less on guessing and my taste. For typesetting of equations as you like to obtain with table people usually use specialized packages (task). As I already said, this again based on guessing.

*Edit:* Let me put attention to selection of column types. Using `l` (as I suggest) is intended for one line text and the width of columns are adopted to the widest cell. Contrary, `p{...}` type has fixed width (2.5 cm in your case) independent to cells content. If it is wider, then it is in normal circumstances broken into more lines (if the nature of contents allowed this). Contents in such cells is not left aligned (as at `l`) but justified (visible in multi-line contents).

I also slightly change the second MWE. In preamble I add package `array` and change columns `l` to `>{$}l<{$}`. With this is indicated, that contents in columns is math and you not need to put each cell into `$ ... $`.

Comment: I want to have one space between the `)` and function.  You had showed me to use `r@{ }l`.  Why aren't you using that code here?

Comment: why? to my taste your request lead to ugly result. if you persist to have `@{}` between `r` and `l`, than just insert it. it will eat space between those two columns, so I not recommended doing this.

Comment: No, I had typed `r@{ }l` and not `r@{}l`.

Comment: sorry, I overlooked this. anyway, difference is negligible. i will added this your request to...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `tasks` package instead:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tasks}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\settasks{
  before-skip=\bigskipamount,
  after-skip=\bigskipamount,
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{tasks}[
  counter-format=tsk[r].),
  label-align=right,
  label-width=2em,
](3)
\task $x^{2}$
\task $x^{3}$
\task $\sqrt{\lvert x \rvert}$
\task $\lvert x \rvert$
\task $\sin{x}$
\task $\ln{x}$
\end{tasks}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I corrected and simplified your code, but it has the drawback you have to type the labels by yourself. A more sensible solution is to use the `tasks` package, which is done for this sort of horizontal lists, or the `shortlst` package, which you'll have to install by yourself, as it's not part of `TeX Live` nor `MiKTeX`, for copyright reasons. Based on shortlst, I defined a `tabenumerate` environment, which does what you want. It uses two keys: `nc`, the number of columns (3 by default) and `il`, the interlinestretch.

Note that with `tasks` the first item is not well aligned, for some reason.

In the following code, all three solutions:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{shortlst, xkeyval,  setspace}

\settasks{counter-format =tsk[r].), label-align=right,  label-offset=1em,before-skip =\smallskipamount, }


\makeatletter
\newcounter{ncol}
\define@key{lex}{nc}[3]{\setcounter{ncol}{#1}}%% 3 columns by default
\define@key{lex}{il}[1.5]{\def\@intln{#1}}% interlining![1]
\newenvironment{tabenumerate}[1][]{%
\setkeys{lex}{nc,il,#1}
\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\mbox{viii.)}}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax}%[1][3]
\setlength{\shortitemwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth/\value{ncol}-\labelwidth-2\labelsep\relax}%
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\roman{enumi}.)}
\setlength\labelsep{0.6em}
\setstretch{\@intln}
\begin{shortenumerate}}%
{\end{shortenumerate}
 }%

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r@{ }l@{\hskip 2.5cm}r@{ }l@{\hskip 2.5cm}r@{ }l}
  i.)  & $x^{2}$           & ii.) & $x^{3}$   & iii.) & $√{\lvert x \rvert}$ \\ [2ex]
  iv.) & $\lvert x \rvert$ & v.)  & $\sin{x}$ & vi.)  & $\ln{x}$
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tasks}(3)
  \task $x^{2}$
  \task $x^{3}$
  \task$√{\lvert x \rvert}$
  \task $\lvert x \rvert$
  \task $\sin{x}$
  \task $\ln{x}$
\end{tasks}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tabenumerate}[il=1.5]
  \item $x^{2}$
  \item $x^{3}$
  \item $√{\lvert x \rvert}$
  \item $\lvert x \rvert$
  \item $\sin{x}$
  \item $\ln{x}$
\end{tabenumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]